# SSRS Rotate 270 not working for IE 11

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

I am Using a Matrix and want to rotate column group headers to 270. I have tried to work around with this problem but didn't got any solution. Does anyone has any suggestion that I can use to fix or work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem generally encountered in SSRS 2005 or older versions of IE, try the link below if it works:

http://bidn.com/Blogs/userid/10/new-features-of-ssrs-2008-r2-part-4-rotating-text-270-degrees